# Conical gradient in Qt (without QConicalGradient)

Tags: c++, qt, graph-algorithm

I have to draw a conical gradient in Qt C++ but I can not use the QConicalGradient. I did have a linear gradient, but I do not know how to make a conical gradient. I do not want the finished code, but I ask for a simple algorithm.

---

```
for(int y = 0; y < image.height(); y++){
    QRgb *line = (QRgb *)image.scanLine(y);

    for(int x = 0; x < image.width(); x++){
        QPoint currentPoint(x, y);
        QPoint relativeToCenter = currentPoint - centerPoint;
        float angle = atan2(relativeToCenter.y(), relativeToCenter.x);
        // I have a problem in this line because I don't know how to set a color:
        float hue = map(-M_PI, angle, M_PI, 0, 255);
        line[x] = (red << 16) + (grn << 8) + blue;
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: *Why* can't you use `QConicalGradient`?

Comment: Because we have to implement your own version of the drawing conical gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code:

Given some area to paint on, and a defined center for your gradient...

For each point that you are painting on in the area, calculate the angle to the center of your gradient.

```
// QPoint currentPoint;  // created/populated with a x, y value by two for loops
QPoint relativeToCenter = currentPoint - centerPoint;
angle = atan2(relativeToCenter.y(), relativeToCenter.x());
```

Then map that angle to a color using your linear gradient, or some sort of mapping function.

```
float hue = map(-PI, angle, PI, 0, 255); // convert angle in radians to value
// between 0 and 255
```

Paint that pixel, and repeat for every pixel in your area.

EDIT: Depending on the pattern of the gradient, you will want to create a different `QColor` pixel.  For example if you had a "rainbow" gradient, just going from one hue to the next, you could use a linear mapping function like this:

```
float map(float x1, float x, float x2, float y1, float y2)
{
     if(true){
          if(x<x1)
                x = x1;
          if(x>x2)
                x = x2;
     }

     return y1 + (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x-x1);
}
```

Then you create a `QColor` object using the outputted value:

```
float hue = map(-PI, angle, PI, 0, 255); // convert angle in radians to value
// between 0 and 255
QColor c;
c.setHsl( (int) hue, 255, 255);
```

Then use this `QColor` object with your `QPainter` or `QBrush` or `QPen` that you are using.  Or if you are putting a qRgb value back in:

```
line[x] = c.rgb();
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: I do not know what I have to do in this line: float hue = map(-PI, angle, PI, 0, 255);
I pasted my code below.